# Should Prometheus exporters be run as sidecar containers or in separate deployments?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

For the general case, I'm wondering if there's a good reason - one way or the other - for running Prometheus exporters as their own Deployments vs. running as a sidecar container in the Pod.

As a concrete example, say I want to monitor an nginx application and plan to use the [nginx Prometheus exporter](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter). Should I:

A: Set up a new deployment with a single container running the nginx exporter, then provide ingress with a service.

B: Add an additional container to the nginx application Pod running the Prometheus exporter.

Comment: Most probably it depends on how many similar pods you have.

Answer (score 4):

Use exporter as a sidecar container in the main pod. We follow this approach to scrape metrics from web based Java applications

Comment: does it matter at all how many exporters are required for the application? Meaning, say instead of just an nginx container in the pod, you had both an nginx and uwsgi container and wanted to export for both. At that point, does it make sense to use two additional sidecar containers in the pod, or offload the export to a separate deployment/service?

Comment: Recommended to have one sidecar container and main container in the pod. Refer standard kubernetes design patterns and decide

Comment: Hello @PEkambaram thank you for you suggestion. Could you please share any yaml example to insert various prometheus exporters as a sidecar to the main pod? Please help